# Creating a simple first module

Tags: 8

I am a total beginner with Drupal and am trying to create a very simple "Hello world" module. I've been following the guide ["A Hello World custom page module"](https://www.drupal.org/node/2464195), but I still get a "Page not found" message.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
    drupal
        modules
            custom
                mymodule
                    src
                     |- Controller
                     |     ExampleController.php
                     |- mymodule.info.yml
                     |- mymodule.routing.yml
```

The module shows up in the admin panel, and I have activated it.

Here's what my routing file looks like:

```
mymodule.content:
  path: '/example'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\ExampleController::content'
    _title: 'Hello World'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Here's mymodule.info.yml:

```
name: Hello World Module
description: Creates a page showing "Hello World".
package: custom

type: module
core: 8.x

dependencies:
  - datetime
  - link
  - views

configure: hello_world.settings

hidden: false

# Note: do not add the 'version'  property yourself!
# It will be added automatically by the packager on drupal.org.
version: 1.0
```

And here's the controller:

```
/**
* @file
* Contains \Drupal\mymodule\Controller\ExampleController.
*/

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class ExampleController extends ControllerBase {

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function content() {
        $build = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => t('Hello World!'),
    );
    return $build;
    }

}
```

When I go to  Configuration/Development/Performance and click "Clear all caches" I get this error message:

```
ReflectionException: Class \Drupal\mymodule\Controller\ExampleController does not exist in ReflectionMethod->__construct() (line 128 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityResolverManager.php).
```

I have tried experimenting with the directory structure, for example moving `mymodule` up directly to `modules` instead of `custom`, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question but you might want to check out Drupal Console, it will help you generate the basic framework for a module and it even has a learning mode. https://drupalconsole.com/

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is embarrassing... By blindly following the guide I forgot to add `<?php` to the beginning of `ExampleController.php`. All these new .yml-files made me forget all about "normal" PHP I guess. Problem solved.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I guess we all know the feeling. Welcome to Drupal Answers by the way!

Answer (score 0):

You can check module examples in [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module, there are really a lot of useful stuff.